# Neo4J results not updating

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I have a very rare problem. I have a java program that inserts into A NEO4j database. The program is working fine on my local_host environment, but when I deployed it to the server(where the neo4j is located) the DB is not updated . Here is what I do

```
//First delete the DB
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db);       
engine.execute("MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r");

Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
//insertion here
tx.success();
tx.close();

//look if it was correctly updated
System.out.println("NODES: " + engine.execute("START n=node(*) RETURN     count(n)").dumpToString());
System.out.println("RELATIONSHIPS: " +engine.execute("START r=relationship(*) RETURN count(r)").dumpToString());
db.shutdown();
```

If I look at the logs everything is working fine

```
UPDATED
NODES: +----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 99       |
+----------+
1 row

RELATIONSHIPS: +----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 76       |
+----------+
1 row
```

But when I look into the Neo4J Db via the browser **nothing has happened** the previous results are **still there**!. Keep in notice that if I run the same program on my **Local_host environment** the behavior is the same but in this occasion **it is correctly updated**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please update your question to include answers to these questions - but I think you'll find your solution with tracking these down:  what DB directory does your web version point to?  When you create this ExecutionEngine in your code, is it tied to an embedded DB?  If so, what's the path on that?  If not, what's the REST endpoint?   My guess is that somewhere, you're pointing to the wrong database.  So the update is happening, but not where you're expecting to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your advice I solved the problem.The issue was the route to the Neo4J DB. When you are running your neo4j program in the same instance where the Neo4J DB is located, you have to specify the path to the folder not the IP. It was actually creating a new neo4j naming it by  the IP.

I used

```
public final static String CONEXION_NEO4J = "/folder/of/neo4jdb/database.db";
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(CONEXION_NEO4J)
```

instead of

```
public final static String CONEXION_NEO4J = "//X.X.X.X/neo4j/database.db";
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(CONEXION_NEO4J)
```

Regards